# Copy files within a ftp server

Tags: vb.net, ftp, copy, ftpwebrequest

I wanted to copy a file from one folder to another folder within a ftp server. For example if a file is on folder1 in a ftp server then i want copy it to folder2. I know how to move or rename the files in ftp server. I also searched in google to copy file within ftp server but i didn't get a work around for it.Also does rdp command line provides facilities like this?  So anyone know how it can be done?
Now i am uploading the same file to two folders separately.So it does take more time.So if it is possible to copy the file then i need to upload only once and then copy it to other folder easily.
So anyone please come up with ideas or codes to do it.
Thank you

Comment: Try this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16865048/copy-files-from-one-folder-to-another-using-php

Answer (score 0):

Regrettably, the answer is simple: there is no FTP copy command. For an exhaustive, well referenced list of FTP commands, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_commands.

In the old days, when FTP was standard, you would have used its companion program telnet to operate in the remote directory.